# Detect touch on object behind another subview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I'm having a rough time detecting touches on a subview which is inserted with `.insertSubView( UIView, atIndex: 2 )`

The reason I cant detect the touches is because there is another view at index 5 taking up the whole screen. I have deactivated user interaction for the view at index 5 and the background is clear, so I can see the object I am trying to touch, but it wont detect it.

The code I use to react to a users touch is:

```
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("touchedAnimObject:"))
self.imageView!.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

The view that is blocking me is setup in the storyboard and only contains a label at the very bottom of the view itself, which is beneath the imageView I am trying to touch.

EDIT:

This is a PageView setup. The code above is in the PageViewController class. The view "blocking" my touch action is my PageContentViewController : UIViewController. As mentioned above, in the Storyboard this only contains a label at the very bottom, has a clear background and user interaction is disabled for the view itself. This view is added to my PageViewController:

```
pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

So, the background for my app, and most of the UI elements are added to the PageViewController, and the PageContentViewController only consists of a view holding a label. But it seems like the PageContentViewController has an invisible layer over the entire screen blocking touch events on elements in lower z-index positions.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code about your view hierarchy. Also I see that you add touch gesture to UIImageView and by default image view has user interaction disabled. Have you enabled user interaction for that view?

Comment: Yes, interaction is enabled for the image. If I insert the image at a higher index the touch function works.

Comment: If you deactivated user interaction for view at index 5 then it will prevent any touch events for underlaying views. So you need to turn interaction at that view.

Comment: Ah, okay :) It doesnt fix the issue itself though, but good to know